# Genymotion and Android Studio layout Bug

Tags: android, genymotion

I started testing out some stuff with Android and Android Studio. I have an **AMD-CPU**, so I can't use the normal **AndroidStudio-AVMs**.

I decided to use Genymotion. When I loaded my first test-app on the genymotion AVM, which is the **Samsung Galaxy S7-6.0.0-API 23**, I had a problem with the layout. Here's an image of the app on the AVM:

[image]

But it is supposed to look like the following picture:

[image]

Comment: make sure you have given the exact same version of SDK inside the Android studio and inside the emulator

Comment: Can you post your layout..?